# No value given for one or more required parameter

Tags: database, listview, ms-access-2013

I want to retrieve data from two tables

1. 1st Table is `exp_head` which contains `exp_ID` and `exp_name` columns
2. 2nd table is `exp_detail` which contains `exp_ID`, `e_date`, `e_amountPaid`, `e_des` columns
3. I want to retrieve `sr_no, e_date, e_amountpaid, e_desciption from
   exp_detail table`, and `exp_name from exp_head` and display in ListView using an inner join

The current query is:

```
    clsCon.list_DataView("
    select exp_detail.sr_no as sr_no, exp_detail.e_date as e_date,exp_head.exp_name as exp_name,exp_detail.e_paid as e_paid,exp_detail.e_des as e_des 
    from exp_detail 
    inner join exp_head on exp_detail.exp_id = exp_head.exp_id 
    where exp_detail.e_date=#" + this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date + "# 
    order by exp_detail.sr_no", this.lstv_ExpDetail);
```

(lstv_ExpDetail) is object of ListView

But I get an error:

> No value given for one or more required parameter

This screenshot shows the ListView where I will display data from two tables

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It is really hard to tell what is wrong right now.

Comment: Why was the question tagged C#? The code snippet contains SQL only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No value given for one or more required parameter

This typically indicates a misspelling of a field name.

Also, the date value must be passed as a string expression:

```
where exp_detail.e_date=#" + this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#
```

Comment: when I reterieve data from siingle table and using this date form this will work correctly.But when I reterive data from two tables.this will not work correctly.

Comment: Error reason is misspell...Thanku dear